# Denote coordinates of subscripted point?

Tags: geometry, notation

Say I have a set of ordered points, like in a polygon, I can name a point in this set $P_i$.

Say I have a high dimensional point and I want to denote its x coordinate, I can do $P_x$ and if I want it's ith coorddinate I can do $P_i$

Say I want the jth coordinate of the ith point, or the x coordinate of the ith point. How do I write that down?

$P_{i, j}$? or $P_{i}[j]$ or what other convention is there?

Answer (score 1):

Let's for example say we want to write the second coordinate of the first point. You can either use commas:
$$P_{1,2}$$
Or parenthesis:
$$(P_1)_2$$
Or, my preferred approach, which is an upper index:
$$P^2_1$$
Though some might prefer something like
$$P^{(1)}_2$$
It comes down to preference.
Any of these are fine if you properly define it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the *[projection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra))* $\pi_j$ to select the $j$-th component of an $n$-tuple. If for instance $P_i=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ is a point with $n$ coordinates we can write
\begin{align*}
\pi_j(P_i)=\pi_j(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=x_j
\end{align*}